# unique pointer memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, new-operator, unique-ptr

I was wondering if anyone could help me to sort out a bit of confusion I have with unique pointers. Consider the following code:

```
// some class "complex" defined here

int main()
{
    while(1) 
    {
        unique_ptr<complex> p(new complex[256]);
        p.reset();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now from what I understand, when I invoke `reset()` on the unique pointer it should delete the object that its raw pointer is referring to. In this case, the object happens to be the very first object of type `complex` out of 256 created. Because that's what `new complex[256]` does, am I right? It simply returns a pointer to the first object in the array (which it, of course, also creates)? So the rest of 256 objects should remain untouched.

Following that logic, the infinite loop should create a memory leak, but that does not happen. I am using MS Visual Studio 2013.

What am I missing? I would be very grateful if anyone could fill me in on what's happening here and confirm or disapprove my conjectures

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `unique_ptr` will call `delete` on the pointer it owns when it goes out of scope. So you're deleting memory allocated by `new[]` using `delete` instead of `delete[]`. That's undefined behavior and it's pretty much pointless to try to reason any further why your code doesn't behave the way you expect it to.

But what might be happening is calling `delete` on that pointer means only the first `complex` object in the array is being destroyed (meaning its destructor gets called). The destructor will not be called for the remaining 255 objects, but the memory occupied by the entire array is still freed.

I think your expectation is for your program to use more and more memory and finally die when the `new` allocation fails, but if the memory occupied by the array is being released, that won't ever happen.

---

The correct way to handle an array with a `unique_ptr` is to use the partial specialization for array types

```
unique_ptr<complex[]> p(new complex[256]);
//                ^^
```

Or if your standard library implements `std::make_unique` (C++14), then use

```
auto p = std::make_unique<complex[]>(256);
```

Comment: Avoiding `new` and using `make_unique` would avoid this kind of error: `auto p = std::make_unique<complex[]>(256);`

Comment: How come the memory is being released without explicitly being told to do so? Is that a compiler specific feature? Finally, is it correct that `std::default_delete<T>` is also used for the array specialization, given that it is used for the primary template? Really appreciate quick responses guys.

Comment: The memory is explictly told to be released inside the `unique_ptr`. That's not a compiler feature, just how the class is implemented. For the array specialization, `T` should be read as `complex[]`, so `std::default_delete<T>` would be `delete[]`

Comment: But the problem is, I tried recreating the above code using regular raw pointers. That is, `complex* p = new complex[256]; delete p` - memory still gets released. So I can't really tie it to the class implementation here. So who's doing this? :) Regarding `std::default_delete<T>` - you were right, thanks. There is an array specialization `struct default_delete<T[]>` invoked for `unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>` unique pointer array specialization, just like @Praetorian mentioned

Comment: @MutomboDikey I don't understand your confusion. `new` allocates memory and constructs the object, while `delete` destroys the object and releases memory. Analogously, the array versions will allocate and construct N objects and destroy and release memory for those N objects respectively. Ignoring that you have undefined behavior because of mismatched `new[]` and `delete`, the `delete` is destroying a single `complex` object and releasing the memory you allocated. It's not required to do so because of the UB, but your implementation might handle this correctly nevertheless.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, new[] and delete mismatch was the source of tge confusion. I just wanted to know in greater depth how come the whole memory gets released without explicitly being told to do so. I simply firmly assumed that this is not possible due to the aforementioned mismatch. But I suppose UB and my particular case happen to do so, just like you said. Thank you for your help!